# Trouble Printing iFrames

Tags: css, iframe, browser, printing

[**Simplified version of this question:**]

Why do iFrames sometimes refuse to print? For example, hit `print preview` on these two pages:

1. http://fiddle.jshell.net/gJDv4/1/show/
2. http://fiddle.jshell.net/gJDv4/2/show/

On print-preview, the iFrames are visible in the first example, but hidden in the second. The **ONLY** code difference between [first](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Skfen/) and [second](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Skfen/1/) iFrames is a CSS property (`margin: 20px;`) has been added to the iFrames in the second example.

---

[**Long (original) version:**]

I am building a preview/print page that assembles a bunch of independent HTML files referencing their own style-sheets and javascript files.

- http://jsfiddle.net/GJKkm/16/

The idea is that all files are displayed in iFrames for preview, and then when printed, each iFrame (which likely will span multiple pages) prints out as if it were it's own document.

However, when I print (or print-preview) the iFrames either show no content, or they only print the first page, truncating the remaining pages of the iFrame.

- http://fiddle.jshell.net/GJKkm/16/show/ (use this link to print-preview, not the one above)

The iFrames printed (and print-previewed) just fine before I made them multiple pages:

- http://fiddle.jshell.net/GJKkm/7/show/

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Hehe, I doubt there is a solution but I will +1 whoever manages to get this working properly :p And +1 for spending the rep on it to get answers while having that little yourself. :)

Comment: If there is no real answer then you surely deserve the bounty for recognizing that right away. ;)

Comment: @sg3s I solved it in my answer below. Waiting for your +1. Lol

Comment: @MedicalDoctor-Programmer Wow, blast from the past! Hahaha. One of the issues was is that the styling information is also iframe specific. Your answer doesn't seem to adres that. But I like the general technical aproach. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can print the documents in the individual  iframes by calling the `print()` function on their windows....

So something like this to print file 2:

```
$('#iframeTwo')[0].contentWindow.print()
```

And here a jsfiddle where I added buttons which trigger the individual prints...

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/GJKkm/17/

As for why the browser doesn't print the content inside iframes when printing their parent document. Probably has to do something with the fact that those documents aren't actually part of the document they're shown in... Think of it like a separate window (one you may generate with `window.open()` in js) but then skillfully hacked into the main document with the viewport limited to whatever is specified on the iframe with some magic.

Comment: The problem with printing the iframes individually is that it opens up the possibility of someone elses print job ending up in between two of the HTML files being printed, since (I assume) they would go into the print queue as separate print jobs.

The explanation about why the content doesn't show up is what I was guessing, but there is still the issue that the iFrames DO show up when they don't overflow on to a separate page!

Comment: If you want to keep your print jobs together you are probably much better off putting the two documents together, taking some extra care to separate the styles using classes... And yes that behavior IS weird, but if you think about it it's amazing they show at all... It probably tries to render it as normal html but since there are limitations to frames the content bugs out. I can't reproduce that in Chrome by the way, so if you're trying to get this to work cross browser you may as well stop now :p

Comment: For bringing the two documents together with different stylesheets. This might be a little work intensive but would probably work; Take the two documents, put the html in seperate 'root' nodes which identify the different documents. Get the stylesheets for the documents, and assemble them in a css pre-compiler within a nested structure (like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules)) let the pre-compiler make the stylesheet, with the nodes inside a nested set that applies the styles in that stylesheet only to the relevant document. Include generated stylesheet. Win.

Comment: I am not opposed to working a solution like what you described, but before I go ahead with all of that, I'd like to be sure that there's no way to do it with iFrames, because the iFrame solution is significantly simpler than what you are suggesting. Why is it "amazing that they show at all"? It was my understanding that this is the whole purpose of iFrames, to embed  other HTML documents inside a parent. My expectation is that if it's no problem to display it on a screen, it should be no problem to print it.

Comment: It may be seem simple but frames are notoriously unreliable, and inflexible. The purpose of iframes is to embed content into another page, however it has been known for some time that iframes are actually a really hard solution to implement in a browser. Normal html view and print view are not the same, you need to separate the different pages etc, doing that with an in-window rendered object is really hard... It is not like a screenshot is made and that the screenshot of the page is sent to the printer.

Comment: Awarded the bounty to this answer because you recognized that there is no solution to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a way to solve it.

The aim is to get the contents of all the iframes into the parent window by manipulating the DOM using javascript.

With this solution you even avoid the problem of the iframe being cut off if it exceeds one page.

Here is the code:

```
<script>

 pages =[] // initiate an empty list here

function printPage() {

var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
// get all the iframes and loop over them
// then push their innerHTML into the list
for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){ 
   pages.push(frames[i].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML); 
;
}
if (pages && pages.length) {

// this if statement, just checks to ensure our list is not empty before running the code.

// here is the magic, we now set the parent window to be equal to all the concatenated iframes innerHTML
window.content.document.body.innerHTML = pages;
// then we print this new window that contains all the iframes
window.print();
} 
else {
// do nothing
}


}
</script>
```

With this you get only one print dialogue box to print all the iframes.

Remember that in your parent page HTML you will have the code below to call the printPage function.

```
<input type="submit" value="Print All"
  onclick="javascript:printPage()"
 />
```

Comment: Basically, by just copying the the html without the stylesheets, you'll lose the styling of the documents. These days we have more tools/optons for scoping CSS, so that is definitely easier now, and possible on the frontend/browser end - but only made easy with some libraries. +1 for the general approach, but a complete solution needs to adres that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have a valid point. 
Anyway, I forgot to mentions that i applied some CSS Printing - @media print rules to the parent page hence my test print came out perfect. I just want to mention it for posterity sake. Thanks.